# Receive errors counter in /proc/pid/net/dev

Tags: networking, linux-networking, linux

Can anyone explain what gets reported in /proc/pid/net/dev in the receive "errs" column:

```
$ cat /proc/1372/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  tun0:   48066     357    0    0    0     0          0         0    44674     567    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 185331707  675072    0    0    0     0          0         0 185331707  675072    0    0    0     0       0          0
virbr0-nic:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
virbr0: 2124211583 1633155    0    0    0     0          0         0 592949203 2019978    0    0    0     0       0          0
 vnet0: 2145591585 1615312    0    0    0     0          0         0 541285976 2448390    0    0    0     0       0          0
   em1: 13209182655 16234239    0    0    0     0          0   1036616 3839455215 8291133    0    0    0     0       0          0
 wlan0: 4499059214 7097706    0    0    0     0          0         0 1073512876 4767214    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

This seems to be per-interface statistics but how are errors collected at the various networking layers?  Does this column simply sum all errors across the stack (Ethernet, TCP, UDP, socket, etc.) or does it report something else entirely?

Assuming a received packet is mangled how can it be correctly attributed to a specific process?

Thanks.